# Adding curve25519 to tinyec

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am testing a TLS server that uses x25519 for key exchange. I am relying on [Scapy-ssl_tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls) for building the TLS connection. However, this tool uses [tinyec](https://herongyang.com/EC-Cryptography/tinyec-What-Is-tinyec.html) as its crypto library, and tinyec  does not have curve25519 in its registry, thus this whole setup does not work.

Does anybody know how could I add the curve25519 to tinyec? Since its 'registry' is just a bunch of hardcoded values (see below), I assume if I had these values for curve25519, that should be enough for my testing.

```
                     "secp192r1": {"p": 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeffffffffffffffff,
                                   "a": 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffffffffffffc,
                                   "b": 0x64210519e59c80e70fa7e9ab72243049feb8deecc146b9b1,
                                   "g": (0x188da80eb03090f67cbf20eb43a18800f4ff0afd82ff1012,
                                         0x07192b95ffc8da78631011ed6b24cdd573f977a11e794811),
                                   "n": 0xffffffffffffffffffffffff99def836146bc9b1b4d22831,
                                   "h": 0x1},
```

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange!  That link under "tinyec" says this:  "tinyec is a tiny library to perform arithmetic operations on elliptic curves in pure Python. It is not a library suitable for production. It is useful for security professionals to understand the inner workings of EC, and be able to play with pre-defined curves."  No wonder it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I read that too, so my expectations were adjusted :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinyec only supports [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#General_theory) [curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Basics), with an equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$. [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) is a [Montgomery curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve), with an equation of the form $B y^2 = x^3 + A x^2 + x$. Tinyec's arithmetic can't do Curve25519 since its $A$ parameter is nonzero.

It would be less work to adapt Scapy-ssl_tls to one of the existing interfaces to Curve25519 than to write Montgomery curve arithmetic yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that was going to be my next step as well.